# How can I write bits to byte array in java?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, byte

I try to create mpegts presentation timestamp. It is 5 bytes length. I found solution in source code of VLC player. It's looks like this (in C lang code):

```
bits_write( &bits, 4, i_pts_dts ); // '0010' or '0011'
bits_write( &bits, 3, i_pts >> 30 );
bits_write( &bits, 1, 0x01 ); // marker
bits_write( &bits, 15, i_pts >> 15 );
bits_write( &bits, 1, 0x01 ); // marker
bits_write( &bits, 15, i_pts );
bits_write( &bits, 1, 0x01 ); // marker
i_header_size -= 0x5;
```

That means I must to collect 5 bytes from 40 bits.
For example, I need to 5 bytes from 2350 decimal number. Binary view:

1001 0010 1110

After VLC manipulation I must have this binary view:

```
0010 000 1 000000000000000 1 000100100101110 1
```

Hex view:

```
21 00 01 12 5D
```

How can I do it in Java?

Also I found Java-solution on GitHub: https://github.com/taktod/myLib/blob/master/myLib.MIT/myLib.container.mpegts/src/main/java/com/ttProject/container/mpegts/field/PtsField.java
But this realization is too difficult. For a one-time operation it is necessary to create too many helper classes like Bit1, Bit2, Bit3, etc...

Comment: You determine how your input bits map to output bytes, e.g. write it on paper, then use [Java bit-manipulation operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) to build that result.

Comment: @Andreas, I know about bit-manipulation operators. For example I can to process 40 bits in String and after convert to long, but long has 4 bytes size. Double has 8 bytes. But I need to 5 bytes. I have no idea how can I do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple bit-manipulation:

```
int dts = 2;     // must be 2 or 3
long pts = 2350; // must be less than 8,589,934,592

byte[] output = new byte[] {
        (byte) (dts << 4 | pts >> 30 | 1),
        (byte) (pts >> 22),
        (byte) (pts >> 15 | 1),
        (byte) (pts >> 7),
        (byte) (pts << 1 | 1)
};
for (byte b : output)
    System.out.printf("%02x ", b); // prints: 21 00 01 12 5d
```

Comment: Oh nice, thanx.